# Vertically align text on one line or two lines within a link

Tags: html, css

I have an anchor tag with some text:

```
<a href="">My Link</a>
```

with this styling so that it will look vertically aligned within a 30px high link:

```
a
{
    width: 90px;
    padding: 13px 0 13px 0;
}
```

The problem is that now there is longer text that doesn't fit in the 90px wide link, so it's causing it to wrap. So the text in the link is pushed down farther, and not vertically aligned within the anchor tag.

Anyone know how I can make sure a link is vertically aligned for text on one or two lines? I don't have the ability to add a class to any links with two lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Text doesn't wrap for me

http://jsfiddle.net/mTJDd/

If you want to vertically align any text, the correct way is to use `line-height` property

[**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/mTJDd/1/)

Comment: The text doesn't say "My Link" anymore, there is longer text in there now that doesn't fit 90px. Also, if I change the line-height, the text for the link with two lines will be really tall, line-height would only work for the single-line link.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [line-height](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/line-height) property.

```
a
{
   line-height:25px;
}
```

Comment: If I change the line-height, the text for the link with two lines will be really tall, line-height would only work for the single-line link.